# How can I make a USB installer for my mid-2009 iMac?

Tags: macos, imac

I am trying to create a bootable USB installer for my mid-2009 iMac, that was completely deleted. Nothing is on the SSD. I tried to boot OS X El Capitan, but it said it could not open the OS X installer .mkpg damaged or missing. I'm running a 2017 iMac on Ventura 13.6.4 to create the install media. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Start at [How can I download an older version of OS X/macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos)

Comment: The direct procedure provided by Apple for creating a bootable USB flash drive installer for OS X El Capitan would be as follows. 1. Download El Capitan from Apple.  2. Use the DiskImageMounter application to mount the download. 3. Use the Installer application to create the Install OS X El Capitan application. 4. Use the `createinstallmedia` command to create the bootable USB flash drive installer. However, **step 3 cannot be completed using a 2017 iMac**. It would be helpful if you could edit your question and further explain how you created the bootable USB flash drive installer.